# What is the best way to plot these anova results in R?

Tags: r

I have this repeated measures ANOVA model here:

```
rm_model <- aov(outcome ~ treatment + age + Error(id/visitnumber), data = new)
```

I want to plot the results in an interpretable way. The model is meant to assesses whether treatment has an impact on weight (outcome) and in particular, that allows the treatment effect to vary over time (which, given the results, we see that the treatment does has an impact on weight).

I tried creating this graph, though it is extremely busy and uninterpretable. What is a better way to graph the results?

[image]

Code I used for the graph:

```
two.way.plot <- ggplot(new, aes(x = treatment, y = outcome, group=id)) +
```

Here is a small sample of my dataset

```
> dput(new)
structure(list(id = c(965, 168, 133, 566, 145, 79, 49, 182, 998, 
476, 314, 578, 800, 712, 574, 858, 743, 260, 155, 493, 411, 397, 
232, 972, 357, 27, 794, 39, 723, 711, 982, 305, 804, 504, 607, 
146, 168, 890, 720, 170, 379, 841, 543, 825, 771, 224, 8, 739, 
876, 844, 5, 308, 997, 275, 802, 552, 683, 488, 743, 61, 439, 
687, 172, 990, 101, 979, 57, 498, 148, 694, 810, 970, 470, 442, 
321, 650, 22, 735, 622, 697, 601, 845, 689, 783, 297, 502, 901, 
902, 907, 933, 831, 848, 238, 244, 562, 238, 54, 307, 157, 833
), outcome = c(178.1292789, 152.6929382, 154.9682105, 180.1792337, 
155.5643838, 158.1777561, 141.2326605, 158.0372637, 170.7657935, 
150.0930737, 144.8978423, 167.7295463, 170.4530778, 166.2320969, 
174.6196961, 172.9699754, 165.6665897, 143.5506991, 150.8801473, 
152.8867248, 141.627696, 147.7234166, 144.2490439, 186.4303623, 
137.4472087, 150.8790336, 175.1623773, 156.37109, 177.8236086, 
170.4165886, 175.8410723, 143.3243023, 159.6941819, 180.1754229, 
163.2772414, 143.8418165, 143.5552981, 172.6175974, 177.6680813, 
137.9041874, 163.4326879, 178.2426015, 173.1707072, 176.0714329, 
165.7867407, 145.6877951, 150.2737186, 184.4544812, 158.2952331, 
182.1838354, 148.9614953, 149.8798918, 156.5142777, 163.2968075, 
177.3107927, 165.4462144, 167.9021459, 148.1217567, 163.2306892, 
145.5216289, 154.5574847, 179.0495321, 145.9386308, 181.1654107, 
144.8315221, 171.6145523, 148.5750191, 144.775874, 148.1463073, 
172.590192, 160.9216146, 174.7643147, 139.3596933, 157.1786811, 
153.3880836, 183.8471692, 148.5695133, 173.8687851, 151.5755017, 
165.0664097, 180.3950209, 164.5429984, 164.983456, 178.9630521, 
137.9087173, 168.668939, 169.8311543, 180.9404174, 174.0725322, 
173.8267465, 174.4805713, 166.6538422, 137.5949582, 152.1977455, 
166.0765327, 148.9605142, 140.4552133, 147.5073477, 146.426167, 
164.9396603), visitnumber = c(4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 
2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 5, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1, 
2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 
2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 3, 1), treatment = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0), age = c(62.56849707, 59.9875489, 58.92425704, 
62.86864989, 55.61336473, 64.98774785, 61.58430531, 66.91110054, 
60.15734064, 61.336864, 56.22408195, 57.41464728, 62.32706193, 
56.24078384, 59.9129205, 59.72669943, 60.7366701, 68.07162556, 
65.83706817, 58.34790981, 62.92541931, 60.44772228, 59.05602316, 
60.3587956, 64.20115418, 53.6724036, 63.85708009, 56.08114237, 
65.0820994, 58.23011895, 62.12986331, 61.85220756, 54.94833195, 
54.9549317, 59.08634974, 66.85477235, 59.9875489, 57.57695066, 
54.79087254, 66.9157855, 66.20755394, 59.35629854, 62.46671274, 
67.65557345, 61.17523285, 60.83744515, 55.4094255, 61.50789629, 
60.07359108, 55.77166234, 66.2290783, 56.01880637, 65.75930218, 
64.63645494, 59.35355296, 62.6060523, 70.28167557, 52.91174325, 
60.7366701, 57.8139364, 58.41752334, 56.53555588, 58.75351312, 
60.74961013, 61.51029989, 54.9842095, 56.00229494, 64.40211717, 
54.86495493, 66.54053274, 53.74773261, 62.06325335, 59.65814464, 
59.07963141, 59.17691183, 53.61106941, 62.58076922, 67.01218874, 
54.08783732, 61.38234868, 61.70638178, 61.59147749, 62.97231388, 
64.1034271, 53.7801112, 62.22005378, 61.43731322, 60.49405197, 
62.2994082, 56.56848077, 59.85286766, 61.65844302, 59.36361724, 
61.53807386, 62.97919029, 59.36361724, 61.85642462, 59.21186756, 
56.24220335, 61.16389981)), row.names = c(4336L, 750L, 596L, 
2524L, 648L, 353L, 211L, 811L, 4487L, 2132L, 1409L, 2577L, 3587L, 
3184L, 2559L, 3854L, 3325L, 1158L, 691L, 2204L, 1842L, 1781L, 
1032L, 4368L, 1602L, 117L, 3558L, 169L, 3237L, 3182L, 4411L, 
1366L, 3602L, 2256L, 2708L, 656L, 752L, 3997L, 3224L, 760L, 1699L, 
3779L, 2427L, 3700L, 3452L, 999L, 35L, 3309L, 3930L, 3794L, 22L, 
1382L, 4481L, 1228L, 3596L, 2466L, 3051L, 2184L, 3324L, 268L, 
1966L, 3073L, 769L, 4450L, 454L, 4396L, 251L, 2227L, 661L, 3104L, 
3629L, 4359L, 2105L, 1978L, 1440L, 2905L, 96L, 3289L, 2774L, 
3119L, 2682L, 3796L, 3080L, 3509L, 1330L, 2244L, 4045L, 4049L, 
4070L, 4190L, 3732L, 3808L, 1063L, 1088L, 2504L, 1060L, 235L, 
1375L, 700L, 3739L), class = "data.frame")

      geom_point(cex = 1.5, pch = 1.0,position = position_jitter(w = 0.1, h = 0))
```

Comment: For a simple boxplot, you could try `boxplot(outcome ~ treatment, data=new)`. If you want to use ggplot (e.g. to group your data), you could similarly use `+ geom_boxplot()`.

Comment: Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/how-to-visualize-what-anova-does) and [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html)